# Using an Objective-C++ file from a C++ file

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, objective-c++

I have a c++ app that I'm trying to port to iPhone and to start off I'm trying to replace my c++ texture loader with an obj-c++ texture loader so that I can make use of the cocoa libraries.

A lot of my c++ files (.cpp files) call the texture loader with something like:

```
GLuint mTexture = TextureLoader::LoadTexture("file.png") //LoadTexture is a static method`
```

but whenever I try to make a TextureLoader class (inside a .mm file) that has Obj-C code, I am forced to make the calling class also a .mm file.

I want to avoid a creep of .mm usage. How can I do it? Is it even possible?

Basically I have a .mm file that has...

```
GLuint TextureLoader::LoadTexture(const char* path)
{
   //...lots of c and obj-c code
   return texture
}
```

and is apart of a c++ class (or is it obj-c++ at this point?)

I want to be able to use it from a .cpp file without having to make the calling class also .mm

Is there anyway to do this?

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do that. However, you are not required to put all C++ member function definitions in a single file - just stick all the pure C++ stuff into `.cpp`, and those that need ObjC into `.mm`.

As well, if you actually have the same repeated ObjC code (perhaps parametrized), then refactor it into a plain C function or C++ class in one separate `.mm` - such that there are no ObjC constructs in the corresponding `.h` - and then use that function/class where needed by including the header.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, you got it exactly. I think the problem was that I must have had Obj-c code in the header file of my texture loading code. That meant that when my c++ code came to include the .h file, the compiler didn't like it.

I'll try and summarise:
Say I have Foo.cpp and Foo.h (c++ only) and Foo.cpp needs to include TextureLoader.h, which contains a c++ class definition whose member methods use obj-c code (in TextureLoader.mm). Make sure there is NO obj-c or cocoa code in TextureLoader.h or else Foo.cpp won't be able to #include it.

Comment: The obvious answer is - don't define your member functions that use ObjC constructs in the header file; define them in .mm file instead.

Answer (score 4):

*I want to avoid a creep of .mm usage. How can I do it? Is it even possible?*

Not if you want to use Objective-C++, no.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is just to compile everything as Objective-C++. You don't have to change all of your extensions; leave 'em as `.cpp` and set Xcode to compile everything as Objective-C++: under the build settings of your project, in the category "GCC X.X - Language", change "Compile Sources As" to "Objective-C++".

(I assume your problem is that you have a whole bunch of `.cpp` files, and you don't feel like renaming them all to `.mm`. Compiling as Objective-C++ will have no effect on the ones that don't actually use any Objective-C stuff (with only *very* rare exceptions), and it'll make your life easier for the ones that do.)

Answer (score 0):

In XCode, right-click on your `.cpp` file and select “Get Infos”. In the “General” tab, change the file type to `sourcecode.cpp.objcpp`. This will build this file and only this file as Objective C++.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the size of the code involved, but if it had a pretty small interface, you could write a C wrapper for your C++ code, and then use `extern C { /* ... */ }` around the header file declarations and function definitions.

This would essentially "hide" the C++ calls from Objective-C, and would allow you to circumvent the requirement of renaming your files from the `m` to the `mm` extension, and/or the requirement of compiling the calling files as Objective-C++.

Objective-C++ uses different compiler rules and is slower than a standard Objective-C compile.